# Get the average on a filtered table but exclude rows where column says 'Draft'

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the average of a filtered table from a column labelled net, but exclude all rows from a column status where the row says 'Draft'

I have tried the below, but just get an error.

=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(1,OFFSET(E10,ROW(Table1[net])-ROW(E10),0)),(Table1[status]="Draft")+0)

EDIT: it should be <>"Draft", that's the formula I am using now

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting a #DIV/0! error but I am starting to think I won't get the average using this formula

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with your current set-up:

1. You are passing a value of 1 as `SUBTOTAL`'s first parameter in an attempt to determine which rows are filtered. This is not correct, however, since that parameter is for obtaining *averages*, and so any filtered rows will return `#DIV/0!` errors. You should be using a first parameter of 3, for example.
2. It's risky creating a formula with a mixture of Structured Table references (`Table1[net]`) and standard A1-style references (`E10`); you should consistently use the former.

All in all:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(INDEX(Table1[net],1),ROW(Table1[net])-MIN(ROW(Table1[net])),0)),
    (Table1[status]="Draft")+0
)
```